# PCA: entire feature space or grouped

Tags: pca, text-mining

Ok let me explain the question: i'm doing text classification using standard tfidf transformations. It happens that my 'corpus' can be divided into groups, for example:  'words in title', 'words in description', etc. In other words, every document is made of sub-documents. So i have the following options:

1 - Perform a separate TFIDF + PCA for every group (that's what i'm doing)

2 - Join all data and perform a single TFIDF + PCA

3 - Perform a separate TFIDF for every group, join the tfidf matrices and perform a single PCA.

Options 2 or 3 will cost a lot of memory, and it's not clear what i gain from that. Any ideas on this? Thank you!